# Show that f is smooth iff $\psi \circ f^{-1} $ is smooth

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

This question was asked in an assignment of Manifolds in an online course I am taking and I was not able to solve it.

> Question : Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a submanifold of dim k, let $\psi : O \subset \mathbb{R}^k \to M$ be a chart for M and let $f : V \subset \mathbb{R}^p  \to  \psi(O) \subset M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a map. Show that f is smooth as map $V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ iff $ \psi^{-1} \circ f : V\to O$ is smooth.

Attempt:  Well, I understand the definitions and results in the course  very well. But I am not able to use the definition of smoothness  in my question.

Please help me!

Comment: @Thomas I have deleted the definition  by editing the question.

Comment: Which definition of "submanifold" do you use?

Comment: @PaulFrost Let $\psi: M \to N$ be $C^{\infty}$. The pair $(M,\psi)$ is a submanifold of N  if $\psi$ is an 1-1 immersion.

Comment: So how is a smooth function defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:V\to\mathbb{R^n}$ be smooth at $x$. Then, there is (depending on definition) a chart $(O,\psi)$ containing $x$ such that $\psi^{-1}\circ f:V\to O$ is smooth at $x$.

Conversely, if $\psi^{-1}\circ f:V\to O$ is smooth, so is the composition with the chart $\psi$ (automatically smooth), $$\psi\circ\psi^{-1}\circ f:V\to \mathbb{R}^n$$